# Javascript: input convert number to dollars

Tags: javascript

I have the following input field where I'm converting a number to a dollar currency format. I have two issues that I'm trying to solve.
The first one is that when the number is in the thousands I would like the first digit to split with a comma (example: 1,089.33). And the second  issue is that when I type something and then try to entirely delete whatever is inside the input it gives me a 0,00. I would like to be able to delete the number entirely inside the input. 
Any ideas on how to fix both of these issues?

```js
function formatAmountNoDecimals( number ) {
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while( rgx.test( number ) ) {
        number = number.replace( rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2' );
    }
    return number;
}

function formatAmount( number ) {

    // remove all the characters except the numeric values
    number = number.replace( /[^0-9]/g, '' );

    // set the default value
    if( number.length == 0 ) number = "0.00";
    else if( number.length == 1 ) number = "0.0" + number;
    else if( number.length == 2 ) number = "0." + number;
    else number = number.substring( 0, number.length - 2 ) + '.' + number.substring( number.length - 2, number.length );

    // set the precision
    number = new Number( number );
    number = number.toFixed( 2 );    // only works with the "."

    // change the splitter to ","
    number = number.replace( /\./g, ',' );

    // format the amount
    x = number.split( ',' );
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : '';

    return formatAmountNoDecimals( x1 ) + x2;
}


$(function() {

    $( '.amount' ).keyup( function() {
        $( this ).val( formatAmount( $( this ).val() ) );
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tSaveext" class="amount" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to use [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)?

Comment: `tSaveext` is an invalid `type` value on `input` elements.

Comment: Your first question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```js
function formatAmountNoDecimals( number ) {
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while( rgx.test( number ) ) {
        number = number.replace( rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2' );
    }
    return number;
}

function formatAmount( number ) {

    // remove all the characters except the numeric values
    number = number.replace( /[^0-9]/g, '' );
    number = number.replace( /\./g, '' );

    // set the default value
    if( number.length == 0 ) number = "";
    else if( number.length == 1 ) number = "0.0" + number;
    else if( number.length == 2 ) number = "0." + number;
    else number = number.substring( 0, number.length - 2 ) + '.' + number.substring( number.length - 2, number.length );

    if(number){
      // set the precision
      number = new Number( number );
      number = number.toFixed( 2 );    // only works with the "."

      // change the splitter to ","
      //console.log(number);
      //number = number.replace( /\./g, ',' );
    console.log(number);
      // format the amount
      x = number.split( ',' );
      x1 = x[0];
      x2 = x.length > 1 ? ',' + x[1] : '';

      return formatAmountNoDecimals( x1 ) + x2;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
}


$(function() {

    $( '.amount' ).keyup( function() {
        $( this ).val( formatAmount( $( this ).val() ) );
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tSaveext" class="amount" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Syed Mohamed Aladeen ... it works just fine :))))

Comment: One more thing @Syed Mohamed Aladeen ... is there a way to delete the entire number if i just hit backspace/delete after I type the number?